# Excel ISNUMBER Function with IF Statement

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have an Excel file I'm working with.  There is a column that contains numbers and text, sometimes it's just one or the other.  I'm trying to write a function that scans the left most part of the cell to see if it starts with a number.  I thought I had it but apparently not.  This is what I had:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(LEFT(E8,1)), "True", "False")
```

This continues to throw me a "false" result even though that particular cell, E8, begins with a "3".  What am I missing here?

Comment: Try `=IF(ISNUMBER(--LEFT(E8,1)), "True", "False")`

Comment: What are the two dashes for?

Comment: The `--` does the same as VALUE() without all the typing.

Comment: Ahhh okay thank you, didn't know that!

Comment: To sum up what is going on, when using the LEFT(), RIGHT() or MID() functions, the output is always a text string, whether it only contains numbers or not.  Therefore, to test if it is numeric we need to try and force that string to a number, with all the methods below it will either return a number or an error.  The ISNUMBER AND IFERROR() all test that outcome.  You have three great answers below, choose the one that you used as the correct answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this out:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(E8,1))),"True","False")
```

Comment: This is perfect.  Thank you!  I didn't even think to use the "VALUE" function.

Answer (score 6):

Using the IF statement is redundant. The most simple and effective way to achieve your desired result is:

```
=ISNUMBER(--LEFT(E8,1))
```

It will automatically return TRUE or FALSE

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can achieve what you require with just the following:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(LEFT(E8)*1))
```

If you do not `LEFT(E8)` evaluates to `LEFT(E8,1)` and multiplication by 1 throws an error on anything non-numeric

If you need your output as strings then update as per below:

```
IF(NOT(ISERROR(LEFT(E8)*1)),"True","False")
```

**EDIT**

Using `ISNUMBER()` is a good alternative to `NOT(ISERROR())`

```
=ISNUMBER(LEFT(A1)*1)
=IF(ISNUMBER(LEFT(A1)*1),"True","False")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR(IF(VALUE(LEFT(E8,1)),"TRUE","FALSE"),"FALSE")
```