# Excel Vba-Similar Function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm so confused in resolving this:

In VBA syntax there is this function:

```
If Left("abcdef",3)="abc" then 
    Msgbox "True"
```

This function is too simple but is there any way for e.g.

To have something like this

```
If left("abcdef",3) is in ["A".."Z"] or if left("1265avd0",2) is in [1..9]
```

Which mean checking if `left ("abcdef",3)` which is equal to `"abc"` is in this Interval ["A".."Z"] or checking `if the left("123avd0",2)` is numeric and is in the interval of [1..9]

Hope you are understading what I want to do

Can anyone Light me in doing This?

Comment: Check this link out and see if it helps https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/365596-check-whether-cell-only-contains-z-1-9-characters.html

Comment: @Dude_Scott thank you for your answer .. I saw that site when I'm seaching for result but the question in that site is looking for formula without using VBA and I want to use VBA here as mentioned in my title EXCEL VBA-Similar Function :-)

Comment: You will need to loop through each letter to check you can use isnumeric for the number. Regex is also a good possibility

Comment: i cant use the function isnumeric because sometimes in cell  there is something like this (25456(T5866/254444) so i need to check if left("25456",5) isnumeric  :(

Comment: `if(isnumber(--left("25456(T5866/254444",5)), ...`

Comment: @Jeeped thank you for your answer , your I found this which is related to your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189049/excel-isnumber-function-with-if-statement ...  so my question I can do this  if(isnumber(--left("25456(T5866/254444",5)) then msgbox "Yes" ???

Comment: So you just want to do a boolean check to see if the first 3 characters are letters (any case) --**OR**-- the first 2 characters are digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regular Expressions ("RegEx") for this.

The pattern has a non-capturing group `(?:...)` that can determine if the start of the string `^` contains either three letters of any case: `[a-zA-Z]{3}` or `|` two digits `\d{2}`.

If either criterion is met, then the `MsgBox` will return **True**, otherwise, it returns **False**.

```
Sub test()

    Dim RegEx As New RegExp, testString As String

    testString = "53bcko390872"

    With RegEx
        .Pattern = "^(?:[a-zA-Z]{3}|\d{2})"
        MsgBox .test(testString)    'will prompt True/False
    End With

End Sub
```

You can replace the `MsgBox` line with something useful, such as

```
If .test(testString) [= True] Then...
```

**[Click Here](https://regex101.com/r/ko5g0q/1)** for a live demo on the regex working (optional).

> **Note** that you will need to set a reference to `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions x.x`

Comment: @K.Davis thank you for your answer ,your result worked perfectly for me , Have a nice day

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Like` operator for this simple type of comparison.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text 'for case insensitive matching
Sub dural()
    Const S1 As String = "abcdef"
    Const S2 As String = "1265avd0"

Debug.Print Left(S1, 3) Like "[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]"
Debug.Print Left(S2, 2) Like "[1-9][1-9]"
End Sub
```

Both will return `TRUE` in this instance.

As pointed out by @chrisneilsen, the comparisons can be simplified to:

```
S1 Like "[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]*"
S2 Like "[1-9][1-9]*"
```

And you can test for either with something like:

```
If Left(myString, 3) Like "[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]" or _
  Left(myString, 2) Like "[1-9][1-9]" then
   'do something
End if
```

And in the simplified version:

```
If myString Like "[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]*" or _
    myString Like "[1-9][1-9]*" then
   'do something
End if
```

More complex pattern matching can be done using Regular Expressions.

If you prefer to not set `Option Compare` then change the alpha patterns to `"[A-Za-z]"`

Comment: Or `S1 Like "[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]*"` and `S2 Like "##*"`

Comment: @chrisneilsen Yes for your first; No for your 2nd.  `#` matches `[0-9]`.  Question asked to match `[1-9]`  But I'll add your suggestion

Comment: fair enough, missed that.  (FWIW some other answers/comments seem to have missed that too)

Comment: Thank you @ronRosenfeld for you answer , but `If Right(Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A4").Value, 6) Like "[0-9][0-9]" Then msgbox "True  else msgbox "false" ` this statement it keeps dispalying me false  and the result is 206310 which number in that range .......And  in `Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A4").Value` I got this  `206310 (206310/D67008)`

Comment: @POLOSTutorials You are matching six digits against two digits. If you want to match 6 digits, and if the range is `[0-9]` and not `[1-9]` as you wrote in your question, then you can use, more simply `If Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A4") Like "######*". I suggest you read `HELP` for the VBA `Like` operator to learn about how to use wild cards.